# Decode raw data within Solidity

Tags: solidity, abi, bytes, solidity-0.8.x, decoding

If I only have the raw input data of a contract call, what would be the best way to decode it into readable form within Solidity?

```js
"[INPUT]":"0x70a08231000000000000000000000000278261c4545d65a81ec449945e83a236666b64f5"
"[OUTPUT]":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
"gas":{
"gas_left":5052320
"gas_used":4814
"total_gas_used":4096237
}
```

I'm doing this but I get a weird number which I don't think it's the right answer:

```js
bytes memory data = '0x70a08231000000000000000000000000278261c4545d65a81ec449945e83a236666b64f5'; 
(uint num) = abi.decode(data, (uint256));
console.log(num);
// 21923419280131834915887268958100430612526877572263439172946489084502927749168
```

If I change `data` to the following, I get:

```js
hex'70a08231000000000000000000000000278261c4545d65a81ec449945e83a236666b64f5'
//50942633119752846454219349998365661925661254240480086959931673327308193899062
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the first four bytes first. The first four bytes of a contract call is the function selector, which specifies which function you want to call, in this case `balanceOf(address)`. I wrote a more detailed explanation about transaction data, which you can find [here](https://blog.mycrypto.com/why-do-we-need-transaction-data-/).

Assuming you're using Solidity 0.6.0 or newer, you can use `data[4:]` to slice off the first four bytes of the input, or additionally just remove them from the input if you're hardcoding the data.

```
function getBalance(bytes calldata data) public pure returns (uint256 balance) {
  (balance) = abi.decode(data, (uint256));
}

// or

function getBalance() public pure returns (uint256 balance) {
  bytes memory data = hex'000000000000000000000000278261c4545d65a81ec449945e83a236666b64f5';
  (balance) = abi.decode(data, (uint256));
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to solidity (as you can see) but I fully understood your explanation and the article (thanks for that), but when I apply the first option you gave I get these errors:

`Index range access is only supported for dynamic calldata arrays`
`The first argument to "abi.decode" must be implicitly convertible to bytes memory or bytes calldata, but is of type bytes memory slice`

And when I use the second option, I get the same long number:
`21923370962747092222049241656982978670225693601166209560647359697270644815409`

I'm using `^0.8.0` btw

Comment: As a follow-up question, if I may, how did you know that the signature of that Method ID was `balanceOf(address)` without having the full hex?

Comment: I updated my answer, it should work properly now. `0x70a08231` is a common function selector and a quick Google search results in `balanceOf(address)`.

Comment: Still the issue though. 

On the first option, it doesn't matter how I pass `data` to `getBalance`, I always get an error of the sort of `Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from literal_string...`. I tried passing it like `"0x70a...."`, `0x70a...`, `hex"70a..."`.

It only works when a change `calldata` to `memory` on the function signature, but I get the same weird long number: `21923419280131834915887268958100430612526877572263439172946489084502927749168`

Comment: As for the second option, I get a different weird long number this time: `225558253637158116798355606682701651365356856565`

Comment: The issue was on my side man. My apologies. I was decoding the input instead of the output.